# Reshape data for D3 stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some csv data of the following format, that I have loaded with `d3.csv()`:

```
Name, Group, Amount
Bill, A, 25
Bill, B, 35
Bill, C, 45
Joe, A, 5
Joe, B, 8
```

But as I understand from various examples, I need the data like this to use it in a stacked bar chart:

```
Name, AmountA, AmountB, AmountC
Bill, 25, 35, 45
Joe, 5, 8, NA
```

How can I transform my data appropriately in the js script? There is also the issue of missing data, as you can see in my example.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This seems to be another [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. So, instead of answering your question, let's forget about reshaping your data and let me ask you this: how do you want to make the stacked bar chart? What are the x and y axis variables?

Comment: Well I planned on following the various examples around the web to make it with d3, but those all start with the data in a different shape. I have tried to reshape the data with `d3.nest()` and `map` without being successful (or really understanding the process). 

The x variable will be categorical (`Name`). Y will be the amounts, stacked by group.

Comment: So, in the x axis, you want two categories, "Bill" and "Joe", and for each one the groups (A, B, C...) as stacked bars, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct that in order to use d3.stack your data needs re-shaping. You could use d3.nest to group the data by name, then construct an object for each group - but your missing data will cause issues.

Instead, I'd do the following. Parse the data:

```
var data = `Name,Group,Amount
    Bill,A,25
    Bill,B,35
    Bill,C,45
    Joe,A,5
    Joe,B,8`;
    
var parsed = d3.csvParse(data);
```

Obtain an array of names and an array of groups:

```
// obtain unique names
var names = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.Name; })
    .entries(parsed)
    .map(function(d) { return d.key; });

// obtain unique groups
var groups = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.Group; })
    .entries(parsed)
    .map(function(d) { return d.key; });
```

(Note, this is using d3.nest to create an array of unique values. Other utility libraries such as underscore have a simpler mechanism for achieving this).

Next, iterate over each unique name and add the group value, using zero for the missing data:

```
var grouped = names.map(function(d) { 
  var item = {
    name:  d
  };
  groups.forEach(function(e) {
    var itemForGroup = parsed.filter(function(f) {
      return f.Group === e && f.Name === d;
    });
    if (itemForGroup.length) {
      item[e] = Number(itemForGroup[0].Amount);
    } else {
      item[e] = 0;
    }
  })
  return item;
})
```

This gives the data in the correct form for use with d3.stack.

Here's a codepen with the complete example:

https://codepen.io/ColinEberhardt/pen/BQbBoX

It also makes use of [d3fc](https://d3fc.io/) in order to make it easier to render the stacked series.

Comment: thanks so much, that worked perfectly with my real data, too